# How do I show X items in UL and hide the rest?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mustache

I was wondering if it is possible to show `X` amount of items in a `UL` and for the rest of the items they can be hidden.

I have a notification widget which I would like to display 5 alerts max. When one gets removed, the next item in the list would be shown so I don't have to remake the list.

Here is my mustache code:

```
var template = 
      '<div class="notifications js-notifications">' +
        '<h3>Notifications</h3>' +
        '<ul class="notifications-list">' +
          '<li class="item no-data">You don\'t have notifications</li>' +
          '{{#items}}' +
            // I would like the li element to be hidden after the first 5 items
            '<li class="item js-item" data-id="{{id}}" alert-id="{{alertid}}">' +
              '<div class="details">' +
                '<span class="title">{{title}}</span>' +
                '<span class="date">{{formattedDate}}</span>' +
              '</div>' +
              '<button type="button" class="button-default button-dismiss js-dismiss">×</button>' +
            '</li>' +
          '{{/items}}' +
        '</ul>' +
        '<a href="#" class="show-all">Show all notifications</a>' +
      '</div>';

    container
        .append(Mustache.render(template, { items: items }))
        .find('.js-count').attr('data-count', items.length).html(items.length).end()
        .off('click', '.js-show-notifications')
        .on('click', '.js-show-notifications', function(event) {
          $(event.currentTarget).closest('.js-show-notifications').toggleClass('active').blur();          
          return true;
        })
    .off('click', '.js-dismiss')
    .on('click', '.js-dismiss', function(event) {
        var item = $(event.currentTarget).parents('.js-item');      
        var alert_ID = +item.attr("alert-id");

        console.log("Item removed: " + alert_ID);       
        var removeItem = function() {

            item[0].removeEventListener(cssTransitionEnd, removeItem, false);
            item.remove();

            // Display the next item in the UL here



            /* update notifications' counter */
            var countElement = container.find('.js-count');
            var prevCount = +countElement.attr('data-count');
            var newCount = prevCount - 1;               
            countElement
              .attr('data-count', newCount)
              .html(newCount);

            if(newCount === 0) {
              countElement.remove();
              container.find('.js-notifications').addClass('empty');
            }
        };

        item[0].addEventListener(cssTransitionEnd, removeItem, false);
        item.addClass('dismissed');
        return true;
    });
```

Comment: CSS code `li:nth-child(-n+5) {display:none}` would help you?

Comment: This works as well. I used `itsgoingdown` solution as I found it easier to configure as I have a "show all notifications" button which i would like to display all elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this. I will wrap it in the `click event` for demonstration: Check the Snippet below

```js
var firstToshow = 0;
var lastToShow = 5;


$("ul li").hide();
$("ul li").slice(firstToshow, lastToShow).show();


$("ul").on('click', function() {

  firstToshow++;
  lastToShow++;
  $("ul li").hide();
  $("ul li").slice(firstToshow, lastToShow).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>14</li>
  <li>15</li>
  <li>16</li>
  <li>18</li>
  <li>19</li>
  <li>20</li>
</ul>
```